# Aster chart created using D3.js is not able to trigger contextmenu event

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, svg, leaflet, markerclusterer

Requirement : An aster chart to be created as marker icon for markers and marker cluster in Leaflet (Google maps). The aster chart should be able to invoke context menu on right click.

I tried attaching 'contextmenu' event while creation of the aster chart, It dint work. So I listen to the 'contextmenu' event on selectAll('g.arc'). The event 'contextmenu' is getting triggered for some of the marker icons, but not for all icons.

```
   /** Create an svg element */
    var svg = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width', w);
    svg.setAttribute('height', h);

    /** Create the pie chart */
    var vis = d3.select(svg)
    //.append('svg')
    .data([data])
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'geo-' + d[0].latLng.lat + '-' + d[0].latLng.lng;
    })
    .attr('class', pieClass)
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .on("contextmenu", function(data, index) {
      contextMenu(this, 'circle', data, index, circles);
      d3.event.preventDefault();
    });

    var arcs = vis.selectAll('g.arc')
    .data(donut.value(valueFunc))
    .enter().append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('transform',
          'translate(' + origo + ',' + origo + ')');

    // White background for segments
    arcs.append('path')
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
    .attr('d', outlineArc)
    .append('svg:title');
```

... ... ....

```
      d3.selectAll('g.arc').on('contextmenu', function() {
           console.log('Context menu triggered');
      });

 return vm.serializeXmlNode(svg);
```

I am serializing svg element. Does it retards invocation of the events?

Please Suggest.